# Find where a picture is taken on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, exif

Is it still possible to find the location information of pictures on facebook since FB doesn't keep the EXIF?

Thanks

Comment: Still, facebook itself manages this somehow: http://www.reddit.com/r/WTF/comments/nkktm/facebook_is_really_creeping_me_out_with_this_how/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Currently Facebook strips the EXIF data upon upload.

The only way to determine where a photo was taken is if the user associated it with a place when they were uploading it to Facebook.

Comment: Just saw an upvote here which reminded me to add this comment: I'm not sure if EXIF data is stripped on upload presently, but I can confirm it's not available via the API unless the user explicitly backdated a photo, otherwise only the upload time is available